# open another chrome app window from a chrome app window

Tags: google-chrome, window, manifest

I have a login window that I open as a Chrome installed Extension (will be a stand-alone chrome web app, so I use the manifest.json to setup the .js file which then opens the little login window.

I want it so that when the user enters correct credentials, and clicks login, I can then open the main application window.

My login window opens fine, but can't get the next window to open.  I'm sure this has something to do with sandboxing, but I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Here's my code for each so far, w/o CSS.

---

manifest.json

```
{
    "name": "CAD",
    "description": "A CAD Call Sheet",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "minimum_chrome_version": "23",
    "version": "0.1",
    "offline_enabled": true,
    "app": {
        "background": {
            "scripts": ["mainInfo.js"]
        }
    },

    "icons": {
        "16": "assets/icon-128x128.png",
        "128": "assets/icon-128x128.png"
    }
}
```

---

mainInfo.js

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
  chrome.app.window.create('CADLogin.html', {
    width: 250,
    height: 250,
    maxWidth: 250,
    minWidth: 250,
    minHeight: 250,
    maxHeight: 250,
  });
});
```

---

CADLogin.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' href="CADLogin.css" type='text/css' />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="CADLogin.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <h1 class="loginHeader">CAD Login</h1>
        </header>

        <form id="loginForm">
            <br />
            <div id="loginUsernamediv">
                <input class="loginFields" type="text" id="loginUsername" name="loginUsername" placeholder="Username" />
            </div>

            <div id="loginPassworddiv">
                <input class="loginFields" type="password" id="loginPassword" name="loginPassword" placeholder="Password" />
            </div>

            <br />

            <div id="loginButtonsdiv">
                <button class="loginButton" id="loginButton">
                    Login
                </button>
                <button class="loginButton" id="cancelButton">
                    Cancel
                </button>
            </div>

            <br />
            <br />

        </form>
    </body>

</html>
```

---

CADLogin.js

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("cancelButton").onclick = function() {
        window.close();
    }

    document.getElementById("loginButton").onclick = function() {
        var username = document.getElementById("loginUsername");
        var password = document.getElementById("loginPassword");
        if (username=="brian" && password=="letmein") {
            chrome.app.window.create('MainSelections.html', {
                width: 100,
                height: 250,
                maxWidth: 100,
                minWidth: 100,
                minHeight: 250,
                maxHeight: 250
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so checking for Typos in my code helps.  texxt/javascript and text/javascript aren't the same...and the first will actually make the code not work.